# Integrating $e^{x^{x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int e^{x^x} $.

taking 
$u$ = $x^x$

so $du= x^x[\log x +1] dx \Rightarrow
 \frac {du}{[u(\log(x) +1)]}$=dx

Now to remove $\log(x)$ from denominator I took $\log(u)= x \log(x) \Rightarrow \log(x) = \frac {\log(u)}{x}$

Again If I use that $\log(u)$ to remove $x$ I get $\log(x)$.

How to proceed from here, Or is there another method to solve this?

Comment: have you asked wolfram?

Comment: Do you think there should be a “closed form”?

Comment: See [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Comment: @Arjang Yes!.It says: no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions in Indefinite integral . But it gives series expansion of the integral at x=0.

Here's the link :" http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e^x^x&lk=4&num=1&lk=4&num=1 "